# Dividing whole variable to a fraction with a variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this expression

[image]

Using distributive property, It became like this

[image]

How did it arrived at $-4a^{-1}a^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $-4a^{-1}a^{1/3}$ is (part of) the given answer? It is wrong.

Comment: @StackTD Not part of the given answer but the previous step before we arrive with the final answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by multiplication we get $$2a^{2+1/2}-4a^{-1+1/2}$$ using the power rule we get
$$2a^{\frac{5}{2}}-4a^{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

Comment: You inadvertently left out the $a$ in the first term. Should be $2a^\frac{5}{2}$